# Qt - Show second Window from Mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to show a second (Tool-)window from a Mainwindow. This should be really basic, but my solution doesn't seem to work (maybe I just can't see it?!).

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    //...

    parametersWindow = new NoiseParamtersWindow;
    parametersWindow->show();
    parametersWindow->raise();

}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the code for the constructor of `NoiseParamtersWindow`?

Comment: Write test code to just show that tool window alone (without ever creating main window) from `main` function. If it does not show then, solve that first. Also note that nothing is shown until you call `exec()` of your application instance.

Comment: The constructor is just: `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool);` Wich seems to be the problem - when I remove it it works fine. But why wouldn't it be possible to show a tool window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are "showing" your tool window inside your constructor for the main window. This makes the tool window "ready" before your main window, which may confuse the windowing system because the child window is ready before the parent.

Try to show the tool window by using a [zero-interval, single-shot timer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#interval-prop). This will show the parameters window once the main window is fully initialized.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    //...

    parametersWindow = new NoiseParamtersWindow;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, parametersWindow. SLOT(show()));
}
```

Comment: @haansn08: This is actually very useful for queuing action to be executed after the application processes existing UI actions. After you use it for a while, you'll learn to like it.

Answer (score 0):

i would highly advice You to do it in a [show()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#public-slots) slot or one of Your own slots. Other then that it should be a standalone window (due to You don't give it a parent) that should show, you might be encountering a bug - but i'm a little rusty with all the changes that digia made to Qt

Comment: Yes, it should be a standalone window next to the Mainwindow. One should be able to click a button to peform actions in the Mainwindow. So Mainwindow needs to know about this window. But I'm not sure what you mean by 'do it in a slot'.

Comment: Please read about signaling in Qt - [Signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) there's a slot on QMainWindow that's called show, it's executed when the window is shown. I believe that's Your desired functionality :)